# Update sqlite3 database simply

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I would like to update my data in a way to keep properties which have their values at **null**  as they were in the table and only change those who have new values as arguments .

This is my request it sends me errors when I have null values in my object :

```
/* THE OBJECT */

    let chick = { ID: 3, name: null, lastname: 'soup', phone: '60-58-22-12', password: null , mail: 'chicken@gmail.com' }

    /* UPDATE REQUEST */

     this.state._stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE user SET 

        name = CASE WHEN (? = NULL) THEN name ELSE ? END ,

        lastname = CASE WHEN (? = NULL) THEN lastname ELSE ? END  , 

        phone= CASE WHEN (? = NULL) THEN phone ELSE ? END ,

        password = CASE WHEN (? = NULL) THEN password ELSE ? END, 

        mail = CASE WHEN (? = NULL) THEN mail ELSE ? END  

       WHERE ID=? ;");

     this.state._stmt.run(obj.name, obj.name, obj.lastname, obj.lastname , obj.phone, obj.phone, obj.password, obj.password, obj.mail, obj.mail, obj.ID);
```

/

/* The error I get is : */

```
[Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.name
Emitted 'error' event on Statement instance at:
] {
  errno: 19,
  code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two way to do that :

**USING COALESCE  THE SHORTER ONE**

```
this.state._stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE user SET 

        name = COALESCE(?, name) ,

        lastname = COALESCE(?, lastname)  , 

        phone= COALESCE(?, phone) ,

        password = COALESCE(?, password), 

        mail = COALESCE(?, mail)  

       WHERE ID=? ;
");
```

**Keeping my request but changing the condition NULL->'null'**

```
UPDATE user 

SET name = CASE

WHEN ? != 'null' THEN ?

ELSE  name END

WHERE ID= ? ;
```